# Wit.ai Promises Issue

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, wit.ai

Using Wit, its calling a custom action, but it doesnt look like the promise is being returned by my function call stack, and I cant see why

https://gist.github.com/mark-stephenson-/e0200233663b2cf1ce1d0a5a33559372

The error I get in the console is:

> Oops! Got an error from Wit: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of
>   undefined at /usr/local/workspace/nodeapps/levelup/index.js:130:9 at
>   Object.activate_schedule
>   (/usr/local/workspace/nodeapps/levelup/index.js:128:12) at
>   /usr/local/workspace/nodeapps/levelup/node_modules/node-wit/lib/wit.js:121:36
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

Ive tried wrapping the LevelUp.set_activation_state function in a promise and returning that, but then the function then doesnt call at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return `this.get_user()` from inside `LevelUp.prototype.set_activation_state`

Comment: Thanks, thats got it.  I thought that with the function containing a promise (that would be returned) it would return that promise automatically without the intrinsic return.